# How to make the size of the Text Widget change with the content in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to design a combined Text widget that consists of two Text widget.

The size of the first Text widget changes as the content changes, and when it reaches the maximum length, an ellipsis is displayed. Like below, the red line part is fixed.

[image]

[image]

Then this is my code:

```dart
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: Text(
        'W',
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      ),
    ),
    Text(
      '(0x1234…1234)',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 12,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

When the length is the largest, the display is normal. But when the length is very small, there will be a blank in the middle.

[image]

So, how do I need to improve my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `Flexible` widget instead of the `Expanded`.

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Flexible(
      child: Text(
        'Was',
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      ),
    ),
    Text(
      '(0x1234…1234)',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 12,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Using a **`Flexible`** widget gives a child of a `Row`, `Column`, or `Flex` the flexibility to expand to fill the available space in the main axis.

While **`Expanded`**, forces the child to expand to fill the available space.

You can also pass the `fit: FlexFit.tight` [The child is forced to fill the available space] or `fit: FlexFit.loose` [The child can be at most as large as the available space (but is allowed to be smaller).] to `Flexible` widget.

By Default it is set to `FlexFit.loose`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is the effect I want.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Flexible instead of Expanded

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Flexible(
      child: Text(
        'W',
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      ),
    ),
    Text(
      '(0x1234…1234)',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 12,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got your question properly, do you want to remove the white space?

```
Row(
   children: <Widget>[
     Expanded(
       child: Align( // add this
         heightFactor: 1,
         alignment: Alignment.centerRight, // this is what you need
         child: Text(
           'W',
           overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
         ),
       ),
     ),
     Text(
       '(0x1234…1234)',
       style: TextStyle(
         fontSize: 12,
         color: Colors.black,
       ),
     ),
   ],
 )
```